# Is it possible to transfer data more than 2 times between two nfc supported android device without moving phones

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

I want to develop an nfc application on android. This application will transfer data from phone A to phone B than B will transfer to A without moving the phones. 
Can I develop an application like this? 
If yes, is there an example?

Thanks..

Comment: AFAIK, you can surely do this. But what do you mean by without moving phones? You obviously can't move phones during data transfer 'cuz NFC range is 4cms.

Comment: i mean transfer data between phones consecutively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the data transferring from Phone B -> A dependent on the data transferred from A->B? If so, then I don't think it's possible without moving the phones. Sending data is dependent on the Touch to Beam UI, currently, so it somewhat hinders what you can do.

To avoid moving the phones away from each other, both users have to touch to beam at the same time.